# error: 'ccc4' was not declared in this scope

Tags: cocos2d-x

I follow the tutorial "Chapter 2 - How to Add a sprite"

and get : Help! error: 'ccc4' was not declared in this scope

without this string :
"CC_BREAK_IF(! CCLayerColor::initWithColor( ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255) ) );" 
works good

what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
CC_BREAK_IF(! CCLayerColor::initWithColor( ccc4f(255, 255, 255, 255) ) );
```